# What Date data type is this returned result from Net::Google::Calendar

Tags: perl, date, google-calendar-api

```
use Net::Google::Calendar;
my $cal = Net::Google::Calendar->new;
$cal->login(...);

 my $c;
 for ($cal->get_calendars) {
    $c = $_ if ($_->title eq 'Custom');
 }
 $cal->set_calendar($c);

 for my $event ($cal->get_events) {
    print "<pre>" . $event->title . " ". Dumper($event->when) ." </pre>";
 }
```

Titles are returned fine but I need the date as well with the hopes of filtering out the events I need by date (Like I do with the calendars for that account, I don't think this module supports a more advanced way anyway).
Theres definitely something there as the printed result shows:

```
VAR1 = bless(
    {
        'local_rd_secs' => 0,
        'local_rd_days' => 734733,
        'rd_nanosecs'   => 0,
        'locale'        => bless(
            {
                'default_time_format_length' => 'medium',
                'native_territory'           => 'United States',
                'native_language'            => 'English',
                'native_complete_name'       => 'English United States',
                'en_language'                => 'English',
                'id'                         => 'en_US',
                'default_date_format_length' => 'medium',
                'en_complete_name'           => 'English United States',
                'en_territory'               => 'United States'
            },
            'DateTime::Locale::en_US'
        ),
        'local_c' => {
            'hour'           => 0,
            'second'         => 0,
            'month'          => 8,
            'quarter'        => 3,
            'day_of_year'    => 231,
            'day_of_quarter' => 49,
            'minute'         => 0,
            'day'            => 18,
            'day_of_week'    => 6,
            'year'           => 2012
        },
        'utc_rd_secs'     => 0,
        'formatter'       => undef,
        'tz'              => bless( { 'name' => 'UTC' }, 'DateTime::TimeZone::UTC' ),
        'utc_year'        => 2013,
        'utc_rd_days'     => 734733,
        'offset_modifier' => 0
    },
    'DateTime'
);
```

'DateTime' is suggestive but `$event->when->day` as per DateTime
gives 
`Can't call method "day" without a package or object reference` Which I assume is me being stupid in using Perl. 
How to use that returned date object (or whatever it is) so that I can read the date directly and/or make it human readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never worked with the module, but browsing its documentation, I noticed

> `when [<start> <end> [allday]]`
>
> ...
>
> Returns two DateTime objects depicting the start and end and a flag
>   noting whether it's an all day event.

So, you can try something like `( $event->when )[0]->day`.

Comment: Thanks its good that a fresh pair of eyes manage to see something in that module's documentation, I certainly cant with the red mist of pure rage Google APIs and this module bring on me.

Comment: Though this is sorted It just shows me that only some random selection of events have been returned instead of all of them or at least the latest ones.

Comment: @Recc: Maybe using `max-results` option to `get_events` might help?

Comment: Dude. Excellent. Didn't see that either.

Answer (score 2):

`ref($event)` reveals that the package for an event is `Net::Google::Calendar::Entry`. Its documentation shows the problem:

```
when [<start> <end> [allday]]
...
    Returns two DateTime objects depicting the start and end and a flag
    noting whether it's an all day event.
```

When you pass that to `Data::Dumper` both `DateTime` objects will be `Dumper`'s arguments. The second parameter to `Dumper` is usually an array reference used as the variable names to use in the output instead of `$VAR1` etc, but as the end date is `undef` `Data::Dumper` uses its default values.

The situation is different when you try to execute `$event->when->day`, obviously, as you're trying to call `day` on an array.